# I want to debug my plugin code using visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, adobe-indesign

I want to debug a code for a sample indesign plugin ( debug 64x) in visual studios. But I am getting the below error when I press the debug button on top(F5).[image]

Comment: Your plugin isn't an executable so you can't "launch" it for debugging. Try starting Indesign and then do Debug -> Attach to process... and select the Indesign process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not an expert in Indesign, but I think it works the same like in other programs:

1. Register your plugin in Indesign;
2. Let Visual Studio start the InDesign executable when debugging: change the Project Settings > Debug > Start External Program path *to the path of the Indesign executable*.

Comment: The issue I was encountering was due to the fact that the mapping for the debug symbols was not set in the linker.